# Jordan normal form options from minimal polynomial

Tags: jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

what is the Jordan normal form options from this minimal polynomial
() = $^3 − 2x^2$. 4X4 matrix

I know of course that the 2 eigenvalues are 0,2.

Comment: Can you tell what the algebraic multiplicities and geometric multiplicities of the two eigenvalues are?

Comment: if i knew that i won't ask the question , need to find all the possible options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

The characteristic polynomial is a multiple of the minimal  polynomial, and they have the same irreducible factors, we face only two possibilities:
$$\chi_A(x)=x^3(x-2),\quad\chi_A(x)=x^2(x-2)^2.$$

Comment: ok , i also get it , but what about the jordan form , we need geometric multiplicities , its right to say that for the first one with $x^3$ the possible geometric multiplicities is 3,1 2,1 or 1,1 ?

Comment: For the case with $x^3(x-2)$, there are are only two possible Jordan normal forms. Check which is a root of the  minimal polynomial (this shouldn't be long with a product by blocks).